# Why are values of input fields persisting after navigation with Jquery Mobile - even if attempts are made to change them?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having trouble with retrieving some of the values from inputs when navigating with the JQuery mobile. When the page is first opened, everything works as expected. However if I navigate away and then back to the page the values of the inputs no longer correspond to the actual values in the field. The html is as follows

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="/static/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="/static/jquery-mobile/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">

        <script src="/static/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/jquery-mobile/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

      <!-- CSS: implied media="all" -->
    </head>


    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id = "main-page">

            <div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;">
            </div>

            <div id = "home" data-role="content">
                <input type = "text" name = "input_a" id = "input_a">

                <select id = "select_a" name = "select_a">
                    <option value = "a">A</option>
                    <option value = "b">B</option>
                    <option value = "c">C</option>
                </select>
            </div>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function set_condition()
            {
                var the_variable = "A";
                var page = $('[data-role="page"]:last'); 
                if (the_variable === "A")
                {
                    page.find("#select_a[value='a']").remove();
                    page.find("[name=select_a]").selectmenu('refresh').val('b');
                }
                console.log($('#select_a').val());
            }

            $(document).off('pageshow').on('pageshow', '#main-page', function ()
            {
                set_condition();
             });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, for example. When I first open the page and select option B and then in my chrome console (and javascript) I type

```
$('#select_a).val()
```

and this returns 'b'. If I then navigate around the remained of the site and then come back to the same page and change the option to option C and type in the same command 'b' is still returned. The same problem is observed with the text input. i.e. if the input is left blank - after navigating no value is returned. Similarly if a number is left in the input field when navigating blank the input field is empty but a value is returned...

So, the values of these inputs are persisting after navigation and are not changing even when, in the case of the select, the value appears to be changed. Why is this?

Comment: The only way I've found to get around this is to disable ajax with                   $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; before the library call. It's not ideal though as the ajaxy nav does save a lot of mobile data overhead.

Comment: Why are you using $(document).off('pageshow')? Try to remove that.

Comment: What are you trying exactly to accomplish? Your code is not clear about the goal you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: Within the < head> section, do the following,

```
<script>
      $(document).on('pagehide', function(e){
           $(e.target).remove();
      });
</script>
```

This will remove any existing page cache in dom. As you may know, the first page (full reload) remains in dom after visiting others.